# Can't drag or move custom NSWindow

Tags: ios, cocoa, drag, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I create a `NSWindowController` and `NSViewController` using Interface Builder, And then, i removed the `NSWindow's` titlebar so that I can custom Window. i create a class subclass `NSWindow` And do following things in class.

```
override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
    return true
}

override var canBecomeMain: Bool {
    return true
}
```

i also set these in `NSWindowController`:

```
{  
    self.window?.becomeKey()
    self.window?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    self.window?.isMovable = true;
    self.window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
}
```

from here, the custom Window is can be dragged,
But when i make the `NSViewController` as the `NSWindowController's` `ContentViewController`, i can not drag the `customWindow`.

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, here was my solution that works (it's in objective-C though, so just throwing it out there in case it helps):

```
@property BOOL mouseDownInTitle;

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   self.initialLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
   NSRect windowFrame = [self frame];
   NSRect titleFrame = NSMakeRect(0, windowFrame.size.height-40, windowFrame.size.width, 40);
   NSPoint currentLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];

   if(NSPointInRect(currentLocation, titleFrame))
   {
      self.mouseDownInTitle = YES;
   }
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   if( self.mouseDownInTitle )
   {
      NSRect screenVisibleFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame];
      NSRect windowFrame = [self frame];

      NSPoint newOrigin = windowFrame.origin;
      NSPoint currentLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];



      // Update the origin with the difference between the new mouse location and the old mouse location.
      newOrigin.x += (currentLocation.x - self.initialLocation.x);
      newOrigin.y += (currentLocation.y - self.initialLocation.y);

      // Don't let window get dragged up under the menu bar
      if ((newOrigin.y + windowFrame.size.height) > (screenVisibleFrame.origin.y + screenVisibleFrame.size.height)) {
         newOrigin.y = screenVisibleFrame.origin.y + (screenVisibleFrame.size.height - windowFrame.size.height);
      }

      [self setFrameOrigin:newOrigin];
   }
}
```

Comment: i have already used the method that you advised , but it is not work for me. when i drag the view, it will be disappear, i thought there maybe some wrong with my dragged view's frame set.

Answer (score 0):

The controlling factor here is the view's `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` property. By default that depends, in turn, on its `isOpaque` property. If you or one of your superclasses override `isOpaque` to return true, then the default implementation of `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` will return false. If you want it to behave differently, then you have to override that, too.

Comment: I am already find my problem, when i drag , what i actually drag is NSViewController's view, i make the window become invisible, i thought it is window, but it is not. i am still confused that i add view on the custom window By xib, it is work, But add a Controller's view on the custom window, it is not work